# ~/.bash_profile Permissions denied

Tags: bash, profile

I am trying add these lines `export PATH=~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to my `~/.bash_profile` however when ever I type `~/.bash_profile` it gives me this error

> -bash: /Users/ryandavila/.bash_profile: Permission denied.

I tried following the instructions on Basic Github checkout (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/README.md#basic-github-checkout) but I get the same error.

Just an FYI I'm very new to ruby on rails yet alone programming.

Comment: can you please run `ls -la ~/.bash_profile` and put the output here?

Comment: hey @JGutierrezC, i have the same issue here is the output of the above command you asked: 
'-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Oct  7 22:10 /home/kashif/.bash_profile' .
What should i do now?

Answer (score 4):

.bash_profile is not executable, which is why you get the error.  To reload it after making changes, use bash's *source* command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or the equivalent alias:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

When you type ~/.bash_profile, you are execute it. You need open this file with text editor and paste `export PATH.....`